# How to deny url using AASA file?

Tags: swift, aasa

I'm trying to deny this url https://foobar.com/foo/bar/test/bar.html

But I want to deny the every url that contains /bar/test/ but this follow AASA file works only if url end with /bar/test/ (https://foobar.com/bar/test/)
How can I solve this? What type hegex is the AASA file?
I also tried */bar/test/* too.

```
{
   "applinks":{
      "apps":[
      ],
      "details":[
         {
            "appID":"appID12345.com.foobarapp.foo",
            "paths":[
               "NOT /bar/test/*",
               "/*"
            ]
         },
         {
            "appID":"appID12345test.com.foobarapp.foo",
            "paths":[
               "NOT /bar/test/*",
               "/*"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```